# Unable to prevent a user with same name as in table from adding using jquery contains check

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jd5pgdz2/4/

When I am trying to add a user with the same name as in my table(the two users displayed are static in my html), it still lets me add it. I am using contains to check if the username already exists in the table by grabbing value from textbox upon create button click . As per my code, it should let it add only if that user name doesnt exist in the table. However, its not letting me do that.

Here is my jquery:-

```
$(document).find("button").button();
$("#create").click(function(){
     var userNamePresentInTable=$("#usr").val();
    if($("table:contains('" + userNamePresentInTable + "')").text() === userNamePresentInTable){
        //$("#error").text(userNamePresentInTable);
      $("#error").text("user already exists");
    }else{

    var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
    var enteredVal=$("#usr").val();

    var td_username=$('<td></td>',{
        text:  $("#usr").val()
    }).addClass("editableFields").appendTo(tr);

    var td_level=$('<td></td>', {
        text: "User"
    }).appendTo(tr);

    var td_buttons=$('<td></td>',{
        html: '<button class="edit">Edit</button> <button class="del">Delete</button> <button class="apply">Apply</button>'
    }).appendTo(tr);

    $(tr).find("button").button();
    $(".userTable").append(tr);
    }
});

    /*For old data already present in the table*/
    $(document).on("click",".edit",function(){
        var currentItem = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
            $.each(currentItem, function(){
                if($(this).hasClass("editableFields")){
                $(this).prop("contenteditable",true);
                $(this).css("border-color","red");
                }
            });
    });

    $(document).on("click",".del",function(){
       var currentItem=$(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(currentItem,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click",".apply",function(){
        var currentItem=$(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(currentItem,function(){
            $(this).prop("contenteditable",false);
            $(this).css("border-color","");
        });

    });
```

Here is my html:

```
    <table class="userTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="uName">Username</th>
        <th class="uLevel">Level</th>
        <th class="uOpt">Options</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="editableFields">User 1</td>
        <td> User</td>
        <td><button class="edit">Edit</button>
            <button class="del">Delete</button>
            <button class="apply">Apply</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="editableFields">User 2</td>
        <td> User</td>
        <td><button class="edit">Edit</button>
            <button class="del">Delete</button>
            <button class="apply">Apply</button></td>
    </tr>

</table>
    <div class="clear"></div> <div class="clear"></div>
       <p>Add User</p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="usr">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="usr" id="usr">
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
           <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
          <button id="create">Create</button>
         <div id="error">
           </div>
```

Comment: Looks to me like a poor choice of logic, or a poor place to store data that needs to be referenced later. If you stored all of that data in an array in addition to that table, it would be relatively easy (and quick/foolproof) to search through it.

Comment: Later on, the backend will have a database but as of now I am just testing on front end

Comment: basically, instead of your table being the data, it should represent the data.

Comment: Currently, your only option would be to reduce your :contains to only looking within the first column of each row.

Comment: In my contains I just replaced table with td and it works! Let me answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jd5pgdz2/5/

```
var userNamePresentInTable=$("#usr").val();
    if($("td:contains('" + userNamePresentInTable + "')").text() === userNamePresentInTable){
        //$("#error").text(userNamePresentInTable);
      $("#error").text("user already exists");
    }else{
```

Basically replacing table just before contains in my if statement with td does the trick.